# How to change the text value of label from another controller which added UIViewController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a `viewController` with container view that embed `TabBarController`. We have added a label control on top in `viewController` with welcome text. Now we want to change the label text value according to `TabBarController` called dynamically. How to change/update label text from another controller in xamarin ios native app.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

The `UITabBarController` has a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate). From your parent view controller you want to assign the delegate to self. When the tab bar changes, update the label.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    let mainTabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup views

        mainTabBarController.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController == <#someViewController#> {
            label.text = ""
        }
        // else ...
    }
}
```